# Call a method from a super class

Tags: objective-c, ios

Couldn't i? i need to call a method from class `A`, this method is in class `B` which inherit from class `A`.

```
@interface B : A
```

in class `A`, when i tried to do something like this:

```
[B foo];
```

I got an error, importing `B` in `A` gives an error too.

Is there any solution to call that method from class `A`? thanx in advance.

Comment: is the method you are trying to call an instance method or a class method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to call the method of a child from the parent, that's a good indication that the method really belongs in the parent to begin with.

Move the method to `A` and your problem goes away.

Comment: I didn't knew that if a make `[self foo]`; in the `A` class, it will call the foo method of `B`. I need to go back to OOP concepts :/ Thanx anyway